# crssync.exe error while installing QGIS 3.0 under Windows 7

Tags: qgis-3, osgeo4w, windows-7

I want to use QGIS 3.0 under Windows 7.
Using the OSGeo4W installer I get the following error message:

```
 The program can't be started because api-ms-crt-runtime-I1-1-0.dll
is missing.
```

Can I use this installer for Windows 7?